# How autoclear a EntryCell in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a EntryCell that need to AutoClear each time the user select it. I know how do that on iOS directly but not with Xamarin.Forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean clear the value when the Entry is Focused this can be accomplished in a few ways.

The easy way: Handling the `Focused` event.

```
<Entry Placeholder="Name" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Focused="Handle_Focused" />
```

and in code behind

```
void Handle_Focused(object sender, Xamarin.Forms.FocusEventArgs e)
{
    ((Entry)sender).Text = string.Empty;
}
```

note that you could also use `((Entry)sender).ClearValue(Entry.TextProperty);` inside your `Handle_Focused` method.

Or with the still easy and cleaner way: Using a `Behavior`

```
namespace YourRootNamespace.Behaviors
{
    public class EntryClearOnFocusBehavior : Behavior<Entry>
    {
        protected override void OnAttachedTo(Entry bindable)
        {
            if (bindable == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Entry was null. Behavior can only be atached to an Entry");
            }

            bindable.Focused += OnEntryFocused;

            base.OnAttachedTo(bindable);
        }

        protected override void OnDetachingFrom(Entry bindable)
        {
            bindable.Focused -= OnEntryFocused;

            base.OnDetachingFrom(bindable);
        }

        void OnEntryFocused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
        {
            ((Entry)sender).ClearValue(Entry.TextProperty);
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your XAML you would:

Add this namespace in your ContentPage definition `xmlns:behaviors="clr-namespace:YourRootNamespace.Behaviors"`

and attach the behavior to your `Entry` (or Entries).

```
<Entry Placeholder="Last Name" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <Entry.Behaviors>
        <behaviors:EntryClearOnFocusBehavior />
    </Entry.Behaviors>
</Entry>
```

This way is my favorite as it gives you reusability.

You can go one step further and create a `Style` with this Behavior so attaching the behavior would be as simple as adding an style. More about this [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/behaviors/creating/).

Hopes this helps.-

Answer (score 0):

You can use trigger, It is very simple solution

```
<Entry Placeholder="enter name">
    <Entry.Triggers>
        <Trigger TargetType="Entry"
             Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
            <Setter 
                Property="Text"
                Value="" />
        </Trigger>
    </Entry.Triggers>
</Entry>
```

**For EntryCell:**

XAML code

```
 <ListView x:Name="listView" SeparatorVisibility="None" ItemsSource="{x:Static local:HomeViewModel.lights}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                    <EntryCell Label="{Binding comment}" Text="{Binding name}" Tapped="Item_Tapped" />
              </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
 </ListView>
```

Code behind

```
 void Item_Tapped(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
         ((EntryCell)sender).Text = "";
    }
```

Comment: The EntryCell not show a Triggers property on code (I don't use xaml)

Comment: @mamcx, If Trigger is not available in EntryCell. then you can use Entry in ViewCell.

Comment: @mamcx, I have updated my answer for EntryCell. It will help you